# How can I solve python-social-auth Bug?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

When I run "python manage.py runserver", I got an Error and a warning,

> /home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py:808:
>   RemovedInDjango110Warning: SubfieldBase has been deprecated. Use
>   Field.from_db_value instead.   return meta(name, bases, d)
>
> /home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py:808:
>   RemovedInDjango110Warning: SubfieldBase has been deprecated. Use
>   Field.from_db_value instead.   return meta(name, bases, d)
>
> Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified some issues:
>
> WARNINGS: ?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were
>   deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes
>   precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into
>   your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

So, I tried.

```
$ pip uninstall python-social-auth
$ git clone https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth
$ cd python-social-auth/
$ python setup.py install
```

But I still have the same error.

And what I added are here.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social.apps.django_app.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
    'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY = 'Your Twitter Key'
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET = 'Your Twitter Secret'
```

urls.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^leon/', include('myapp.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
] # + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

What should I do for the error?
Any advice is grateful.

Thank you.

Python 3.5.1,
Django 1.9.2

Comment: What is the error? I only see warnings. Additionally, you note in a comment that you can "solve" some warnings. If you can and they're not relevant to the error, please do so rather than make us investigate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS entries under TEMPLATES -> OPTIONS -> context_processors

This is what I have:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS':True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.debug',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.core.context_processors.media',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
                'django.core.context_processors.tz',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Thank you, Derek. I could solve the part of template warning.